# Python, Не работает цикл 'for' в боте Telegram

Tags: python, циклы, telebot, for

У меня есть "игрушечный" telegram - бот, в котором пользователь может пройти регистрацию. Система получит его данные (имя, город, информация о пользователе) и запишет её в текстовый файл.

Я написал следующий скрипт (привожу здесь только его часть):

```
#TODO: Логика проверки regFlag
#Если user id у нас есть, regFlag ставим на TRUE

setup_text = ['Введите ваше имя: ','Введите ваш город: ','Добавьте информацию о себе: ']
check_text = ['Имя: ', 'Город: ', 'О себе: ']
setup_user = ['','','']
tempNumber = 0

#setup_textNumber не определён. Я делаю что - то не так?

'''
setup_user[setup_textNumber] = info
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
'''

def register(message,setup_textNumber):
    ask = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, setup_text[setup_textNumber])
    #Выведено сообщение с просьбой вбить данные
    bot_register_next_step_handler(ask, savedata)

def savedata(message):
    info = message.text
    setup_user[tempNumber] = info

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я записал такую информацию: ' + info)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['setup'])
def setup(message):
    for i in range (0,2):
        i = tempNumber
        register(message,i)
        
    if i == 2:
        regFlag = True
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вот данные вашего профиля')

        for d in range(0,2):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, check_text[d] + setup_user[d])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Данные введены правильно?')
        #TODO: Логика запуска цикла по новой
        #regFlag заменить на False
        #TODO: Выписать все данные  в файл
```

Немного модифицировав его, я вставил код в основное тело бота. Мой код работает неправильно, я где - то накосячил с циклом for, и я не могу найти ошибку.

Когда я пытаюсь зарегистрироваться, бот дважды спрашивает моё "Имя" (то есть, `setup_text[0]` срабатывает дважды, но **не выводит** `setup_text[1]`, `setup_text[2]`)

Точно таким же образом, бот дважды выводит сообщение

> Я записал такую информацию: Имя

" (это значит, что имя сохраняется в список `setup_user[0]`, поскольку метод берёт данные из него).

Не могли бы вы помочь мне найти ошибку в цикле?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу где у Вас меняется `tempNumber`. В цикле Вы постоянно будете присваивать переменной i значение `tempNumber = 0` . Соответственно условие `if i == 2:` никогда не исполнится и `setup_text[1]`, `setup_text[2]` тоже не выполнится, только с 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range (0,2): # тут можно сократить до range(2), т.к. 0 - значение по умолчанию
    i = tempNumber # <- эту строчку нужно убрать
    register(message,i)
```

Всё, что под `if i == 2:`, как и само `if i == 2:` можно тоже убрать, потому что в данном коде `i` никогда не станет равным 2.